# Which vs. Whose

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns, grammar-myths, possessive-pronouns

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> "These kind of branding strategies are adopted by those firms and organisations **whose** sales are decreasing day by day.

Or

> "These kind of branding strategies are adopted by those firms and organisations **which** sales are decreasing day by day.

I just want to know which one should I use: **which** or **whose**. As far as I know, **whose** is used for living things and **which** for non-living things. But using "which" doesn't sound correct in this sentence.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76780/discussion-on-question-by-kuldeep-sharma-which-vs-whose).

Answer (score 17):

The correct word to use here is **whose**.

*"As far as I know whose is used for living things and which for non-living things"* - that's not correct.  [We use *whose* for both living and non-living things](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/whose-for-inanimate-objects) (although some people think it sounds bad to use it with non-living things) and *whose* and *which* have different grammatical functions.

Roughly speaking,

- *which* means "the ones that"
- *whose* means "possessing the ones that"

Consider this as an example: some leaves have fallen off some trees.  We would say

> The leaves which have been lost

or

> The trees whose leaves have been lost

One is about the things themselves, the other is about the things that own the other things.  So in your original sentence, it is not the companies that are decreasing day by day; the companies own the sales that are decreasing.

Answer (score 8):

Who told you that *whose* is only used for living things? I'd like to know the name of that person who is responsible for speeding this misconception about the English language because I hear people refer to it as fact all the time on this forum. The statement that *whose* can only be used for people and animals is just not true. You can definitely use it for nonliving objects. Period!

The relative pronoun *whose* is used to indicate that something belongs to or is owned by someone or something else. So, the "thing" something belongs to can be a living thing as well as a nonliving one. *Whose* has a very strong notion of possession which *which*, also a relative pronoun, does not have. That's why your second sentence sounds wrong. Take a look at these examples:

> Do you remember the company **whose** managers were all from the UK? Well, it went bankrupt last year. *(this sentence sounds absolutely normal)*
>
> Do you remember the company **which had** managers **who** were all from the UK? Well, it went bankrupt last year. (*which mangers were* would be grammatically incorrect English)

Comment: MWDEU nicely puts it while commenting on the results of a survey (1974) in which the majority of participants marked *whose* wrong: *The specter of the 18th-century grammarian is still loose in the land.*

Comment: Teachers used to teach that whose was for people and animate things. That is a fact. But I cannot prove and I don't agree with it.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin, thank you for spreading the truth! Although, I'd argue that you should have used `the company **that** had managers` instead of `the company **which** had managers`.

Comment: @ccjmne Aghh, you're probably right. It was very difficult to come up with a good example where you could easily substitute *whose* with *witch* and clearly see that the sentence grammatically breaks apart. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ccjmne Why? *Which* is perfectly grammatical in that sentence.

Comment: @userr2684291: It's very commonly admitted that [`which` and `that` have different purposes](http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/which-vs-that).

Comment: @ccjmne A relative clause beginning with *which* can be either a supplement or a modifier (i.e., "non-restrictive" or "restrictive", respectively). Only usage manuals whose authors are divorced from the reality of the English grammar prescribe that it is one way or another. This has been so since the 17th century and it hasn't changed since, according to MWDEU. The subordinator *that*, in fact, started this same way in the 14th century, i.e., as introducing both "restrictive" and "non-restrictive" relative clauses, but over the time it has decayed to introducing the "restrictive" ones only.

Comment: @userr2684291: I'm sorry, I was on my phone at the time and the SO app apparently doesn't support any of that! Would you please help me locate that source of information in the MWDEU? I could not find it using Google — but I admit I might just not know how to do it best. Going back to my previous question; I am genuinely wondering why you would ask me something you already know the answer to. If you want reputation or a more detailed explanation, don't ask me in the comments but [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I'll be happy to answer there.

Comment: @userr2684291: And if it's a (please keep it cordial) debate you're after, let's [take it to chat](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/164967/which-vs-whose/164971?noredirect=1#) :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76777/discussion-between-userr2684291-and-ccjmne).

Answer (score 6):

> These kind of branding strategies are adopted by those firms and organisations *whose* sales are decreasing day by day. ✓

> **whose**: used to say which person or thing you mean
>   e.g. *It's the house whose door is painted red.*

Source: [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/whose)

Comment: “used to say which person or thing you mean” is worse than useless; all relative pronouns are used that way, and not only that way.

Comment: @AntonSherwood: "all relative pronouns are used that way" They are different: "who" and "whom" refer to people, "which" refers to things, "when" and "where" refer to time and place, "why" refers to the reason, and "that" is used instead of "who/whom/which".

Comment: A distinction which has nothing to do with the point I raised.  Yes, different pronouns are used for different classes; but all relative pronouns, **not only *whose*,** are used to distinguish between members of a same class.

Answer (score 5):

> These kinds of branding strategies are adopted by those firms and
>   organisations **the sales of which** are decreasing day by day.

That's how you would say it with **which**.  You need **of** to form the "possessive" with **which**.

This is not to say that **whose** would be wrong.

Comment: Now,  I would accept whose but your explanation is exactly what my comment above said, which was questioned by one user as if I were saying something out of this world.....That said, your answer has the merit of showing exactly how this works. Personally, I'd get rid of it altogether: those organizations with sales that are decreasing day by day. Same meaning without whose or of which.

Answer (score 4):

The correct form is **whose**:

> Branding strategies of this kind are adopted by those firms and organisations **whose** sales are decreasing day by day.

The word **whose** [can be used with inanimate objects](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/23541/48335).

Comment: *A* correct form is **whose** ;-)   We can also say "the sales of which".

Comment: A user under my comment above is questioning that whose is the sales of which. Could you (Tᴚoɯɐuo) put him or her straight on that? Thank you.